# How to send props in Vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-props

I am quite new in vue so I haven't understood the logic completely. My question is I have ticket and ticketlist components. So I am not on my ticket list component I am creating some tickets data and I want to show them according to the ticket component. To make it more clear here is my ticketlist component:

```
<template>
    <section class="tickets">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12 col-md-3 mb-3">
                    <Ticket v-for="ticket in tickets" :key="ticket.id" :product="ticket"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</template>

<script>
import Ticket from './Ticket'
export default {
    components: {
        Ticket
    },
    data() {
        return {
            tickets: [
                {
                    id: 0,
                    category: "Einzelkarte",
                    price: "€3,50",
                    tariff: [
                        "Wählen Sie eine Option",
                        "Erwachsene",
                        "Erwachsener erm.",
                        "Kinder / Jugendliche",
                        "Kinder / Jugendliche erm.",
                    ],
                    available_amount: 23,
                    article_number: "2021.05.04-2673990197-1",
                },
            ],
        };
    },
}
</script>
```

And also ticket component:

```
<template>
  <widget type="ticket" class="--flex-column">
    <div class="top --flex-column">
      <div class="bandname -bold">Ghost Mice</div>
      <div class="tourname">Home Tour</div>
      <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/199011/concert.png" alt="" />
      <div class="deetz --flex-row-j!sb">
        <div class="event --flex-column">
          <div class="date">3rd March 2017</div>
          <div class="location -bold">Bloomington, Indiana</div>
        </div>
        <div class="price --flex-column">
          <div class="label">Price</div>
          <div class="cost -bold">€{{ ticket.price }}</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="rip"></div>
    <div class="bottom --flex-row-j!sb">
      <a class="btn button" href="#">ADD TO CART</a>
    </div>
  </widget>



</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ['ticket'],
}
</script>


<style scoped>
@import 'https://i.koya.io/flex/1.1.0.css';

*, ::after, ::before {
   box-sizing: unset;
}
</style>
```

So, I am showing TicketList component in one of the page but the thing is it doesnt show anything. So I wonder how can I connect them together and show tickets data according to ticket component. I hope I am clear but if I am not I can answer you in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

The probleme is the props name, you need to pass `ticket` as props and not `product`

```
...
   <Ticket v-for="ticket in tickets" :key="ticket.id" :ticket="ticket"/>
...
```

or the contrary inside you `Ticket` component set :

```
props: ['product']
```